# What is the height of the net in Haikyuu?

Tags: haikyuu

Is it ever directly stated in the show or manga how high the net is? Otherwise, is there a way to extrapolate it, or is there any information on Japanese high school net heights?

Comment: I think like most shows(including anime), equipment related specifics are assumed to be standard where it applies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if *Haikyuu!!* ever specifically talks about it - it doesn't come up in the anime through the end of season 2, at least -  but the net height for high school boys' volleyball is [reportedly](http://www.sports-rule.com/volley6/about/) 240 cm. (Contrast 243 cm for pro men's volleyball, and 220 cm for high school girls' volleyball.)